# Как можно сократить код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Я написал программу цель которой сохранять числовое значение с дальнейшим увеличением его. Однако мне кажется что есть способ сократить или упростить мою программу так как планирую её использовать в другой программе

```
def y():
    with open(p, 'r' ,encoding="utf-8") as f:
        return f.read(32)

def u(x):
    with open(p, 'w' ,encoding="utf-8") as c:
        x = str(x)
        c.write(x)

def r():
    with open(p, 'w' ,encoding="utf-8") as c:
        c.write('1')

p = 'jo.txt'
y()
x = int(y())
print(x)
a = input()
if a == 'r':
    r()
    print('прогресс сброшен')
else:   
    for i in range(10):
        x+=1
        u(x)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во первых, если вы хотите и дальше использовать этот код, лучше называйте переменные подробно, чтобы потом не ломать голову что значит `y()` и т.д., а так же напишите комментарии.
Сидеть и разбираться в вашем коде, довольно трудно без всего этого.

Не нужно сокращать код, если собираетесь его переиспользовать. Просто положите его в отдельный модуль.

```
class Saver:
    encoding = "utf-8"

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def read(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'r', encoding=self.encoding) as f:
            return f.read(32)

    def write(self, value):
        with open(self.filename, 'w', encoding=self.encoding) as f:
            f.write(str(value))

    def reset(self, default_value=1):
        self.write(default_value)

saver = Saver('jo.txt')
x = saver.read()
print(x)
a = input()
if a == 'r':
    saver.reset()
    print('прогресс сброшен')
else:
    for i in range(10):
        x+=1
        saver.write(x)
```

Если же вы хотите именно сократить ваш код, то я бы посоветовал переписать функцию `r()` через используя `u()`, как в моем примере